# What is the maximum memory allocation size in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management

My C++ code that works well on 64-bit Linux systems have a memory allocation error in Visual Studio 2013. This is the memory allocation part that causes the problem:

```
int main() {
   unsigned char* bit_vector;
   bit_vector = new unsigned char[1662068170];
}
```

Can I ask what is the maximum size of memory allocation in Visual Studio and how I can increase it?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Do you use x64 platform in Visual Studio project?

Comment: Does the data really need to be contiguous?

Comment: Of course, my real code is more complicated. I just take a problematic part of the code and change a variable to a constant that is the value of the variable when the problem happened.

Comment: @AlexFarber The problem has gone after I change the platform to x64! Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @Bathsheba Can I ask what I can do if the block does not need to be contiguous?

Comment: You want some kind of data structure that is *almost* contiguous. *i.e.* something not as disparate as a linked list but not as blocky as a vector. A vector of vectors might work. Or draw your inspiration from BLAS sparse matrices. Unfortunately the C++ standard library has no such structure, so you'd have to search for one or build your own. That said, I'd be dismayed if you can't allocate a 4GB block on Windows x64.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the ability of the OS to allocate a continuous block of memory..

Try using  using a linked `list` (e.g., `std::vector`) for the same purpose. 
It has the same interface / order of operation - and it allows to use memory in a much more efficient way

Comment: Good advice in many circumstances but the OP has clarified that the data block must be contiguous. By the way, std::vector is not an *example* of a linked list, and std::vector is guaranteed by the standard to have contiguous data.